# Getting out of ban

Tags: discussion

In the help center it is given that I will get out of ban when my positive contribution will outweigh my those questions which were poorly received.Can someone tell me how much positive reputation I have to gain to get out of ban.I went throughout all the instructions given in help center I just want to know exact number of positive remarks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Nobody's going to reveal the actual numbers that Stack Exchange uses for such rules.

Also see: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/270345)